# Is this expected reverse DNS behaviour or something weirder?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, android, busybox

Excuse me as I'm a linux noob:

I have a system (specifically, a Nexus 7 running CM 10.2.1 with busybox), which, when I run `host` or `traceroute` on its nominal private IP (`192.168.1.7`) gives a hostname of `192-168-1-7.tpgi.com.au`, `tpgi.com.au` being the back end of my ISP, regardless of what I set the device hostname as.

I assume at this point that what is happening is that the device is not giving any hostname and as such a reverse DNS query is executed, with my ISP giving the aforementioned 'dummy' hostname. No other devices on our network are named like this. Forward DNS gives nothing for this hostname.

The weird thing is that when I ran `nmap` on the device IP, I got some filtered services that didn't seem to have anything to do with android, CM or busybox (not sure if it's advisable to post here). I'm kinda worried I've somehow port-scanned a system belonging to my ISP and I'm not too keen on experimenting further in this direction for fear that my ISP thinks I'm trying to be some kind of super-hacker. The weirder thing is that `traceroute`s to this IP are much slower than to other systems on the LAN, although I heard that the OS I'm using (Ubuntu 13.10) doesn't maintain a local DNS cache so it might be doing a reverse DNS lookup every time I run `traceroute` on the affected IP.

Any ideas as to what is going on? I know it's a provincial question but I imagine similar things might happen elsewhere.

EDIT:

running `traceroute` on `192.168.1.7`:

```
traceroute to 192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192-168-1-7.tpgi.com.au (192.168.1.7)  146.478 ms  147.016 ms  147.361 ms
```

This is different to connections to external hosts which pass through the router, `192.168.1.1`.

If I disconnect the router from the internet:

```
traceroute to 192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7)  103.670 ms  106.129 ms  108.237 ms
```

Note the change in hostname.

When I run nmap on 192.168.1.7 with the internet disconnected it tells me that every port scanned is closed. I can confirm that I am hitting the intended device in this scenario as nmap fails if I turn the device network adapter off.

Comment: please post the nmap results with the port numbers it finds...   shoul d be fine.

Comment: What does your resolve.conf file show (ie what is in the domain and search strings)? A pcap of a host command or traceroute might also tell you something about where information is coming from.

Comment: @Richie086 - I'm not entirely certain it would be lawful in Australia to do so, however I've added some additional information which may be edifying.

Comment: @MaQleod - resolv.conf simply contains `namesever 127.0.1.1`, `search Home`. I've added some traceroute info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected based on the minimal information you've shared.

When your ISP link is up, you're (almost certainly) using their DNS servers (you haven't posted that config though, of your router DHCP settings).  Whatever DNS server that is, it has a reverse-mapping zone that covers 7.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa and it is resolving a PTR looking for that name to 192-168-1-7.tpgi.com.au.  `Host` and `traceroute` are using reverse-DNS lookups to "help" you.  Simple as that.

Now what is dyamically configured via DHCP and what is statically configured, I don't know, you didn't post that, but could also have a bearing on your results, i.e., the DNS server is used by the device you are running the `traceroute` from.  If you point to 8.8.8.8 for a DNS server, you will get a different result.

Comment: Well, this answers the hostname issue, though I still have no idea what host I hit with my nmap scan or how it was even possible...